# Moving files from one subdirectory to another

Tags: bash, file-move

I tried moving files from one directory to another and didn't work. so I searched and found an answer that fits what I want. When I run it, modified to my directory, it gives

What is want to do:

> `${filename,,*}`: bad substitution!

This is what I used:

```
for filename in *; do
  case "${filename,,*}" in
    b01.nii*)    mv "$filename" "$/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/str" ;;
    vol_01.nii*) mv "$filename" "$/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/rs" ;;
    *)           echo "don't know where to put $filename";;
  esac
done
```

Thank you

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Shell (bash) in Mac terminal!

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ill try!

Comment: Same.. ${filename,,}: bad substitution

Comment: Have you put a `$` in `$/Users/dave..` by mistake, was that suppose to be a variable? .. Also your `$filename` could have some trouble chars, try using 2 dashes like this `mv -- "$filename" ..`

Comment: I just realised my mistake but i am still getting the same error!
Ok, so i have a file called test. Inside it there are several files called untitled_folder_000 to untitled_folder_999. Inside each there are 2 folders and 2 files. The folders are 'str' and 'rs' and the files are b01.nii and vol_01.nii. I want to put b01.nii inside str and vol_01 inside rs in all files! Thats it!

Comment: Are you sure this is being run by bash?  Is there a #!/bin/bash line at the top?

Comment: the main problem is the `for` command, the variable `$filename` contains `*` and not the real file name. you should use`for filename in $(find . -name "*");do`

Comment: It might be because you're using an old version of Bash (bash<4). The expansion `${var,,}` appeared in Bash 4.

Comment: Ok, i gave up, i really have been trying many different version of this code.
Any other way around this?

Comment: So, i did this now

    for file in `ls test`
    do
    mv /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder****/t1.nii
    /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder****/str

the reason why i have ** in my code is because i have a lot of files to transfer (1500~). 
It didn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

you two errors:

the main problem is the for command, the variable `$filename` contains `*` and not the real file name. you should usefor filename in `$(find . -name "*");do`

the second one is the case:

**you have to be sure** about `$filename` variable's value i.e. in my bash shell the filename output is

```
./b01.nii 
./vol_01.nii
```

it's better to use the following syntax in the case `./b01.nii* )`

I've replaced your `mv` with `echo` just to test the script:

```
for filename in $(find . -name "*"); do

  case ${filename} in
    ./b01.nii* )    
                echo "$filename ${filename}/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/str" ;;
    ./vol_01.nii* ) 
                echo "$filename ${filename}/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/rs" ;;
    *)          
                echo "don't know where to put $filename";;
  esac
done
```

my output is

```
sh-4.3$ bash -f main.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
don't know where to put .                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
don't know where to put ./main.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
don't know where to put ./.cg_conf                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
don't know where to put ./myfile_12345                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
don't know where to put ./myfile_17676                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
don't know where to put ./myfile_9898                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
don't know where to put ./Newfile.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
./b01.nii ./b01.nii/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/str                                                                                                                                                                                       
./vol_01.nii ./vol_01.nii/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*/rs
```

Regards

Claudio

Comment: Don't parse the output of `find`! it's broken if there are filenames containing spaces or glob characters. `for filename in *` is the proper way to loop through files in Bash.