# Moving files from one subdirectory to another II

Tags: bash, sh, move, file-management, file-move

My directory is like this:

```
/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_0001/vol_0000
/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_0001/rs

/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_0001/t1
/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_0001/str
```

I want to move all `vol_0000` to `rs` and `t1` to `str` in 1500~ `untitled_folder_`**** inside test in a shell script if possible.

I already tried many times, but got no where.
im writing this anew because i was not able to get help before.
Here is the previous thread!
If this was answered i will delete that one for redundancy.

[Moving files from one subdirectory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598698/moving-files-from-one-subdirectory-to-another)

Comment: Do you want get it done using shell script? If so then mention in question in question and also mention what you  have tried so far ?

Comment: I added a link to what i have tried!

Comment: So you want to move all the files named `vol_`*  from `untitled_folder_0001` to the `rs` subfolder of  `untitled_folder_00001` (which is a different folder from the first one, with an extra 0 in its name)? Or is `vol_0000` a subfolder whose contents you want to move to that folder? 

And you also want to move all the files from `t1` in some other folder to a directory named `str` that's in the same parent folder as `t1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving files from one subdirectory to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598698/moving-files-from-one-subdirectory-to-another)

Comment: @Mark Reed, thank you for pointing this out! 
I fixed it, in the Q again!
I have almost 1500+ folders inside test (untitled_folder_0001 ~ untitled_folder_1678). Each contains the above 2 files and 2 folders. I want to put the files in their designated folders!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please check the note at the end of this Q!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is probably with a loop.

```
for f in /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*; do
  mv "$f"/vol_0000 "$f"/rs # move everything from `vol_0000` into `rs`
  mv "$f"/t1 "$f"/str
done
```

... assuming I've understood the goal correctly.

Comment: Output

    mv: rename /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_1/vol_0000/* to /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_1/rs/*: Not a directory

    mv: rename /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_1/t1/* to /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_1/str*: Not a directory

    mv: rename /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_2/vol_0000/* to /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_2/rs*: Not a directory

    mv: rename /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_2/t1/* to /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_2/str*: Not a directory
...

Comment: Why are you putting `*`s on the destination names?

Comment: Sorry it seems that i am not able to explain my directory properly.
each folder untitled_folder_0001 to untitled_folder_**** contains (/Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_0001/), these four items
vol_0000 (file)
rs (folder)
t1 (file)
str (folder)
I want to move col to rs and t1 to str in all the untitled_folder_**** that i have!

Comment: I copied the code exactly as you put it!
This is exactly what i did!

    for f in /Users/dave/Desktop/test/untitled_folder_*; do
      mv "$f"/vol_0000/* "$f"/rs # move everything from `vol_0000` into `rs`
      mv "$f"/t1/* "$f"/str
    done

Comment: Oh, vol_0000 and t1 are *files*,not subfolders.  OK, see edited answer.

Comment: will do once i have 15 reputations! Sorry, just started with this!